# Worksheet_Calculate() to only work for selected row

Tags: excel

I have an issue where I want to call a Macro from a formula. The formula in question lies in column "T" (specifically "T3:T1000").

### I have tried using the following code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()

    For Each c In Range("T3:T1000")
        If c.Value = "F" Then
            Call SendEMailSC
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

---

This code works, however it works for every line where the formula is satisfied by result "F". where I only need it to apply to the current edited row.

Does this make sense?

I also have tried the following code:

---

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()

    If Range("T3").Value = "F" Then
        Call SendEMailSC
    End If
End Sub
```

---

However this only works for T3.

please help!!

Comment: What does SendEMailSC do? And what isn't working here? Your top snippet of code looks like it would loop through t3:t1000 and for each instance where the value is "F", it would call "SendEMailSC". What are you looking for this to do?

Comment: SendEmailSC is simply another Macro I wish to run when the condition of 'F' is met in column T. However, I only wish the macro to be called for when the condition of 'F' is met for the selected row. (if that makes sense). This is the reason why I generated the second code. to only look at specific rows...but this only looks at row3.

Comment: The problem is that if column T has multiple conditions of 'F' then the SendEMailSC macro gets called multiple times, I only want it for the selected row. Thanks

Comment: Even if I could identify the Row in question that resulted in the "F" condition, I could let the macro run for that Row, then get the macro to delete out the "F" for that row. but I cannot identify the row.

Comment: It still isn't very clear what you are trying to do. What do you mean "run for that row"? It would be very easy to identify which row the F resides in within column T.